# How to use Likert Scale data in regression analysis?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, likert

My knowledge about statistics is elementary and I would really appreciate some help or suggestions in solving my current problem. I am doing a dissertation and I will collect the data using a likert scale. My question is can I use that likert scale data to run a regression analysis to find out the relation between dependent and independent variables?

For example,

Q1. I just need a clean bed and a decent bathroom in my hotel > 1 2 3 4 5 (Suppose, Factor 1)
Q2. I must have a direct bus service > 1 2 3 4 5 (Factor 2)
Q3. .... (Factor 3)

Suppose, I already know income and expenditure. Now how can I achieve this:

Expenditure = a + B1(income) + B2(factor 1) + B3(factor 2) + B4(factor 3)

Is there a way to do this? Or should I use a different approach?

I am actually trying to find relation between "domestic tourism expenditure" and different factors.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you searched our site for [Likert and regression](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=likert+regression) yet? This kind of question is so popular I'm confident you will find plenty of good advice by looking through those results.

Comment: Hi, I have checked some questions but with no exact answer. But yes, I could look some more. :)